# My Gravatar works on Meta but not on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, gravatar

I have cleared my cache but I still don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the main site is stackoverflow.  Make sure your email is set correctly on both site profiles.

Comment: Thanks I'm a retard.  I was so sure I hadn't made a mistake.

Comment: We are all retards some days. :)